# Google Mock a method that returns void but takes a std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I was wondering if it is possible to use gmock framework to mock a method that takes a unique_ptr with only forward declaring the type:

```
class A; 

class interface
{
   virtual void SetA(std::unique_ptr<A>) = 0;
};


class GmockInterface
{
   MOCK_METHOD(void, SetA, (std::unique_ptr<A>), (override));
};
```

It throws an error see declaration of A because it does not know how to destruct it, I try the trick with return types for unique_ptr but it did not work...

```
class GmockInterface
{
  MOCK_METHOD(void, SetAProxy, (A*));

  void SetA(std::unique_ptr<A> a) override
  {
     SetAProxy(a.release());
  }

};
```

Comment: Your second version [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/zrG9zshaj), can you provide the error that you saw when you used it?

Comment: (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\memory(2400): message : while compiling class template member function 'void std::default_delete<A>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=A
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\memory(2512): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::default_delete<A>::operator ()(_Ty *) noexcept const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=A
1>        ]

Comment: I'm afraid MSVC is right here, From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr): *If the default deleter is used, `T` must be complete at the point in code where the deleter is invoked, which happens in the destructor, move assignment operator, and reset member function of `std::unique_ptr`.* You need `A` to be complete type, because the destructor of `unique_ptr` will be invoked (even if it's nullptr).If you cannot include definition of A before mock, I think you could move definition of your proxy function to after A is included?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to considering another tool for actually generating the mocks, the [Mimicc](https://mimicc.dev) user guide actually has an example covering a very similar (arguably more complicated) case [here](https://mimicc.dev/mimicc-resource/userguidehtml/#types-requiring-move).

You should still be able to use Google Test for testing purposes, just use Mimicc to generate the source code for the mock as a separate step.